# Does ArgoCD perform kubernetes build to detect out-of-sync

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, kustomize

I refactored my k8s objects to use Kustomization, Components, replacements, patches and got to a good DRY state so that I don't repeat much between 2 apps and between those across dev and test environments. While doing so I am referring to objects outside of the folder (but same repository)

```
components:
  - ../../common-nonprod
  - ../../common-nonprod-ui
```

My question is will ArgoCD be able to detect a change in the app if any of the files inside the common folders change that this application refers to as `components`.

In other words does ArgoCD performs `kustomize build` to detect what changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. ArgoCD runs `kustomize build` to realize your manifests before trying to apply them to the cluster. ArgoCD doesn't care which files have changed; it simply cares that the manifests produced by `kustomize build` differ (or not) from what is currently deployed in the cluster.